# Ubuntu Multipass systray text-menu not appearing

Tags: menu, system-tray, multipass

[image]

I just upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. I found a problem in the Multipass systray menu. When I right-click the Multipass systray, the menu showing without any text inside.

I have try to remove the Multipass and remove the snapshot, then re-install again after restart the laptop but the problem is still exist.

```
sudo snap remove multipass
sudo snap forget 20 (the multipass snapshot #)
sudo snap install multipass
```

Any idea of what could be causing this and if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a font caching issue. If so, one of these two commands should resolve the issue:

1. Force re-generation of apparently up-to-date cache files:

   ```
   sudo fc-cache -f
   ```
2. Erase all existing cache files and rescan:

   ```
   sudo fc-cache -r
   ```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's still not worked, but thanks anyway